# ADsys Group Policy Objects - User Policies not Caching or Processing

Tags: 22.04, active-directory, sssd

I've got a 22.04 system joined to Active Directory, ADsys installed, a few group policies created. User authentication works fine, machine/computer policies are applying successfully. However, user policy settings don't seem to be caching or applying to the system.

Are there extra configuration items needed to have user policies processed? I've gone through the documentation as best I can, haven't been able to find anything that looks to apply here. The user account being signed into is in an AD OU where the GPO called "Ubuntu User" is linked, User Settings are enabled.

```
$ adsysctl policy update -av
INFO No configuration file: Config File "adsys" Not Found in "[/var/cache/adsys/policies/U-3GTRXJWRUPDOW /home/testuser /etc /usr/sbin]".
We will only use the defaults, env variables or flags. 
INFO Downloading "assets"                         
INFO Apply policy for U-3GTRXJWRUPDOW (machine: true)
```

```
$ adsysctl policy applied --details
ERROR Error from server: error while displaying applied policies: failed to dump policies for "testuser@ad.testlab.com": no policy applied for "testuser@ad.testlab.com": can't get cached policies from /var/cache/adsys/policies/testuser@ad.testlab.com: open /var/cache/adsys/policies/testuser@ad.testlab.com/policies: no such file or directory
```

```
$ ls /var/cache/adsys/policies
U-3GTRXJWRUPDOW
```

```
$ cat /var/cache/adsys/policies/U-3GTRXJWRUPDOW/policies
gpos:
    - id: '{1F00F6F9-7DDA-400B-96D0-C7CEE5D38A0A}'
      name: Ubuntu-Machine
      rules:
        privilege:
            - key: client-admins
              value: |
                adminuser@ad.testlab.com
              disabled: false
    - id: '{3C3DF920-9466-4FE9-97D0-7CA3AE9E6B75}'
      name: Ubuntu User
      rules: {}
    - id: '{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}'
      name: Default Domain Policy
      rules: {}
```

```
$ realm list
ad.testlab.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: AD.TESTLAB.COM
  domain-name: ad.testlab.com
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: winbind
  required-package: libnss-winbind
  required-package: winbind
  required-package: libpam-winbind
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: AD\%U
  login-policy: allow-any-login
ad.testlab.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: AD.TESTLAB.COM
  domain-name: ad.testlab.com
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
[sssd]
domains = ad.testlab.com
services = nss, pam
default_domain_suffix = ad.testlab.com
full_name_format = %1$s

[domain/ad.testlab.com]
ad_enabled_domains = ad.testlab.com
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
ad_gpo_map_remote_interactive = +dcv, +dcv-graphical-sso
ad_gpo_ignore_unreadable = true
cache_credentials = true
ignore_group_members = true
subdomain_inherit = ignore_group_members
krb5_store_password_if_offline = true
ad_gpo_access_control = disabled
```